# Getting stuck with error: Model is not defined

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code in ASP MVC. Im trying to get the model as parameter for getting the right folder in js for playing music.

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(item.Mp3file));
            <button onclick="getLocation(model)">Click me</button> 
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

When i click on 'Click me' I want JS does save the value in a var. So i created the var model where i store my location of my mp3file. When i click this the function getLocation(model) must be entered in the system. But it wont cover

My function in JS

```
function getLocation(model) {
var tekst = model;
console.log(tekst);}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: have you declared @model on top of you view page?

Comment: in which way can i call it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to reference your server side code with the "@":

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(item.Mp3file));
<button onclick="getLocation('@model')">Click me</button>
```

Comment: that would definitely work if it was a simple type, but it's a complex model. Out of curiosity (I can't test it right now), does that syntax serialise the model automatically to JSON? Because if not, this won't be sufficient, and a suitable serialisation method would have to be used instead.

Comment: The Html.Raw(Json.Encode(model)) serializes model to JSON.

Comment: that should probably be in your answer then?

Comment: var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(item.Mp3file));  That is in my answer, and in the OP.  So, @model is a JSON formatted object.  Wrapping it in '' will allow it to be sent to a JS function.

Comment: you know what. I totally missed that, and in the OP. Sorry. Serves me right for logging on in the evening after a long day.